# Creating touch event reactions without one in MapsForge

Tags: java, android, touch, touch-event, mapsforge

I am trying to offline make map viewing app using MapsForge code integreted into an other programm. They work in layers. In first layer there is the other programm. Touch events happen in this layer. According to  the touch event the programm generates outgoing data such as 3 units in X direction and 4 units in negative Y direction. I want to deliver the data to MapsForge so that it creates the corresponding  reaction. How would this work with my code sample? What should I change? 
I also have these libraries: androidsvg-1.2.1.jar, GtfBridge.jar, mapsforge-map-android-release-0.5.2.jar, SwingMapViewer-release-0.5.2.jar

```
package com.example.gtflauncher;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import org.mapsforge.core.model.LatLong;
import org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidGraphicFactory;
import org.mapsforge.map.android.util.AndroidUtil;
import org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView;
import org.mapsforge.map.layer.cache.TileCache;
import org.mapsforge.map.layer.renderer.TileRendererLayer;
import org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDataStore;
import org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapFile;
import org.mapsforge.map.rendertheme.InternalRenderTheme;

import java.io.File;

public class NavigationService
{
private MapView mapView;
private TileCache tileCache;
private TileRendererLayer tileRendererLayer;

private File mapFile;

public NavigationService(final Activity appActivity, final String modelPath)
{

   mapFile = new File(modelPath + "/maps/", "baden-wuerttemberg.map");
    if(!mapFile.isFile())
    {
        Log.e("NavigationService", "mapFile '" + mapFile.getAbsoluteFile() + "' couldn't be found.");
    }

    // Init MapView
    mapView = (MapView) appActivity.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setClickable(true);
    mapView.getMapScaleBar().setVisible(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMin((byte) 10);
    mapView.getMapZoomControls().setZoomLevelMax((byte) 20);

    // create a tile cache of suitable size
    tileCache = AndroidUtil.createTileCache(appActivity, "mapcache",
            mapView.getModel().displayModel.getTileSize(), 1f,
            mapView.getModel().frameBufferModel.getOverdrawFactor());
}

public static void initGraphicsFactory(final Application application)
{
    AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(application);
}

public void startNavigation()
{
    if(!mapFile.isFile())
    {
        return;
    }

    // 48.779209, 9.1772152 = Stuttgart
    mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setCenter(new LatLong(48.779209, 9.1772152));
    mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setZoomLevel((byte) 12);

    // tile renderer layer using internal render theme
    MapDataStore mapDataStore = new MapFile(mapFile);
    tileRendererLayer = new TileRendererLayer(tileCache, mapDataStore,
            mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition, false, true, AndroidGraphicFactory.INSTANCE);
    tileRendererLayer.setXmlRenderTheme(InternalRenderTheme.OSMARENDER);

    // only once a layer is associated with a mapView the rendering starts
    mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(tileRendererLayer);
}

public void shutdownNavigation()
{
    mapView.destroyAll();
}
}
```